# Get AWS Cloudwatch metric for DynamoDB throttled Requests

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

I am trying to create a metric in AWS cloudwatch to see how many throttled Requests we have on our Dynamo DB. I am struggling with creating this metric. The Danymo DB default dashboard only shows empty graphs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oKP0.png)

Do I have to add a new Math Metric to see the throttles? I cannot find any info on that online and would love some help!

I used the explore feature already and didn't find the needed metric. Also no information on how to create the Sum that I might need

Thank you so much in advance
Tempa

Edit:
I read the part of aws documentation - but I can't find the needed metrics in my aws cloudwatch. Not the throttledRequests (as mentioned) and also not the ReadThrottleEvents and WriteThrottleEvents. Also the metric I showed in the picture above - it's empty because there is no METRIC behind it. If I open it and try to edit - it's empty :(

Answer (score 0):

This metric is published by default, for eg: [ThrottledRequests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html#ThrottledRequests).

The reason the graphs are currently empty is because you must first be throttled before they are populated. If you wish to see them populated, then you can force throttling by setting the reads or writes to 1WCU/RCU and drive a small amount of traffic at the table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I read the part you sent me - but I can't find the needed metrics in my aws cloudwatch. Not the throttledRequests (as mentioned) and also not the ReadThrottleEvents and WriteThrottleEvents. Also the metric I showed in the picture above - it's empty because there is no METRIC behind it. If I open it and try to edit - it's empty :(

Comment: You cannot edit it. As I said, metrics do not exist unless they are published to. So force throttling for one of your tables to see those metrics populated, and thus you will see they graphs in DynamoDB and CloudWatch Consoles.